# Good practice to extract data of a multi input table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large table of inputs and on click event I need to extract the input values of each row to send them to the server.

I need to ask if there is a better way to do it to prevent all that hard coding.
My below code works somehow, but I haven't checked if the input has type radio, so I need to write more code to finalize it.

I am not sure if am doing well or if you can share a better way on this.

Here is what  I do below:

- Iterate over each table row and assign each row id to the object as a
  key.
- Iterate over that object to get each row's input values
- Save the input to the object as values seperated by `_` to be splitted as an array

[Live Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEC0OTT9XXDS)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <table>
        <tbody id="dynamic_form_tbody">
            <tr id="123">
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="date"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="yes"> <input type="radio" name="choice" value="no"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="1256">
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="date"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="yes"> <input type="radio" name="choice" value="no"></td>            </tr>
            <tr id="1212">
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="date"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="yes"> <input type="radio" name="choice" value="no"></td>            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="log" value="console.log data">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(() => {
            var $btn = $('#log')

            $btn.click(e => {
                var table_tbody = $('#dynamic_form_tbody')

                var dynamic_form_data = {}
                //collect each row's id
                table_tbody.find("tr").each(function (e) {
                    console.log('tr found with id: ' + $(this).attr('id'))
                    id = $(this).attr('id')
                    dynamic_form_data[id] = ""
                })

                for (let id in dynamic_form_data) {
                    $(`tr#${id} input`).each(function (e) {
                        let $this_val = $(this).val() || null
                        dynamic_form_data[id] += [$this_val + '_']
                    })
                }

                console.log(dynamic_form_data)
            })

        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why `[$this_val + '_']` with array conversion?

Comment: Is this better? https://jsfiddle.net/fhza8gLt/

Comment: an array of an array? Not really. Please provide expected content of `dynamic_form_data`. Should each property be a single string, an array of strings, an array of arrays of strings?

Comment: So it should be an object with key-values. Key is the id of the row. Values should be the inputs

Comment: My question is about the values. Are they supposed to be arrays, or strings? If strings, then why do you use square brackets at all?

Comment: @trincot values should be arrays.

Comment: Please provide the expected value of `dynamic_form_data` in JavaScript notation, based on the example HTML you have given.  You are asking for a "better way", but currently `dynamic_form_data` values are *not* arrays, and there are several other issues.

Comment: Also, if you expect arrays, then what is the use of `"_"` in your code? You seem to want to create a concatenated string with "_" as delimiter, not an array. This is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- Your radiobuttons all have the same name, so that you can only select one in the whole table. I suppose you should be able to select one in each row.
- `$(this).val() || null`: `null` is not useful, as an empty string is fine. If you decide to produce a string instead of an array, then `null` becomes "null", which is indistinguishable from an input that really has those characters. I would therefore drop `|| null`.
- `[$this_val + '_']` converts a string to an array, but then that array is immediately converted back to a string when assigned with `+=`.
- `+ '_'` will add also an underscore after the last value.
- Both radio button values (yes, no) are always added to the result, without taking the selection into account. You should only take the one that is `checked`
- To avoid that neither of the two radio buttons is selected, provide a default in the HTML definition, using the `checked` attribute

There seems no reason to not do the job in one cycle instead of two. You can select all the inputs that are not radio buttons, plus the checked radio buttons.

```js
$(() => {
    $('#log').click(e => {
        var dynamic_form_data = {};
        $('#dynamic_form_tbody').find('tr').each(function () {
            var $inputs = $(this).find(':checked,input:not([type="radio"])');
            dynamic_form_data[$(this).attr('id')] = $inputs.map(function() {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get(); // Chain `.join("_")` if you want a string instead of array.
        });
        console.log(dynamic_form_data);
    });
})
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody id="dynamic_form_tbody">
        <tr id="123">
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="date"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="choice123" value="yes" checked> <input type="radio" name="choice123" value="no"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="1256">
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="date"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="choice1256" value="yes" checked> <input type="radio" name="choice1256" value="no"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="1212">
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="date"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="choice1212" value="yes" checked> <input type="radio" name="choice1212" value="no"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="log" value="console.log data">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes sorry for confusion. The point is to send the data to python for processing. I think arrays (as you did) is the way to go. Thanks

Comment: Sir, by the way, what's the use of  `.get()` is this necessary ?

Comment: `.get()` converts a jQuery collection to a standard array. It is necessary. Alternatively, you can use `$.map`: the syntax is a little different, but it returns a standard array, and so you would not need `.get()`.

Comment: Okay. I've shorten it further: `dynamic_form_data[$(this).attr('id')] = $.map( $inputs, e=> e.value) `